# A sleep script for Ubuntu server

Tags: command-line, scripts, suspend

Let's start from the beginning: I have a Pi which wakes up my server when a request comes in on `tcpdump`, and it works like a treat!

My problem is that I want my server to sleep when there is no incoming data for, let's say, 30 mins. The server is used only by me, both from within and outside my LAN.

I think that I need to use `tcpdump` in a shell script to monitor the port or the IP and, if there is no incoming, it will react to it. 
I have an idea to do this, because I have looked around on the internet for 2 days, and tried a lot of things, but I can't succeed.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that "no incoming data" means: `tcpdump` is not printing any line. Therefore we have to start a 30 minute timer and reset it whenever `tcpdump` prints a line.

Starting it is fairly simple:

```
sleep 30m && poweroff
```

How do we reset it? Simple: we kill `sleep` and restart it.

How do we detect new lines from `tcpdump`? A good old `while read -r` loop.

Putting everything together:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

shutdown-timer() {
    # Waits 30 minutes and shuts down the computer.
    sleep 30m && poweroff
}

reset-timer() {
    # Kills 'shutdown-timer' (if it's running) and
    # restarts it, saving its PID in 'timerpid'.
    if [[ -n "$timerpid" ]]
    then
        kill "$timerpid" || true
    fi
    shutdown-timer &
    timerpid="$!"
}

# Start the timer for the first time.
reset-timer

tcpdump | while read -r line
do
    # A new packet was sent or received.
    reset-timer
done
```

Note that there might be disturbing packets every now and then. For example you might have configured APT to check for updates every 5 minutes. This will prevent the computer from shutting down, because the timer would be reset every 5 minutes.

If you need, you can filter the output of `tcpdump` using `grep` or whatever tool, like this:

```
tcpdump | grep -v archive.ubuntu.com | while read -r line
```